# Is there a function which returns to upper bound of a Scala range?

Tags: scala, function, collections, range

Create a simple range in Scala: `val range = (1 to 10)` Now I wanna find a function that returns the upper bound of this range like: `val upper = range.max (upper: Int = 10)` Or something to that effect, is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can browse the Scaladoc to find available methods. From what I understand `end` is what you're looking for:

```scala
range.end
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html#end:Int